# Testing omniauth with cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, omniauth

I am looking for help testing omniauth authentication with cucumber. I have tried following a tutorial (http://samuelmullen.com/2011/05/simple-integration-testing-with-cucumber-and-omniauth/), but it doesn't seem to be calling the session controller at all.

Here is what I have so far:

features/support/env.rb:

```
Capybara.default_host = 'example.org'
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:twitter, {
  :uid => '12345',
  :info => {
    :name => 'twitteruser',
  }
})

OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook, {
  :uid => '12345',
  :info => {
    :name => 'facebookuser'
  }
})
```

step definition:

```
Given /^I am signed in with provider "(.*)"$/ do |provider|
  visit "/auth/#{provider.downcase}"
end
```

scenario:

```
Scenario: a user can log into facebook
  Given I am signed in with provider "facebook"
  And I am on the profile page for "facebookuser"
  Then I should see "facebookuser"
```

Any clue why this isn't working? :/. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changed contents of env.rb to this and now works.

```
Before('@omniauth_test') do
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
  Capybara.default_host = 'http://example.com'

  OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:twitter, {
    :uid => '12345',
    :info => {
      :name => 'twitteruser',
    }
  })

  OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook, {
    :uid => '12345',
    :info => {
      :name => 'facebookuser'
    }
  })
end

After('@omniauth_test') do
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = false
end
```

Comment: Can I please provide your complete code as I am practicing the Cucumber Rails Devise Omniauth social API testing